# Let $\,E=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: |x| \le 1,|y|\le 1\}.$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck with the following problem:

> Let $\,E=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: |x| \le 1,|y|\le 1\}.$ Define $f \colon E \to \Bbb R$ by $f(x,y)=\frac {x+y}{1+x^2+y^2}$ .Then the range of $f$ is :
>
> 1. connected open set
> 2. connected closed set
> 3. bounded open set
> 4. closed and unbounded set.

In case of option 4, it is not unbounded as $|x| \le 1,|y|\le 1$ and hence $1+x^2+y^2 \le 3$ and also WLOG by taking $ 0 \le x,y \le 1$, we get $x+y \le 2$ and hence $f(x,y)$ must be bounded set. So, option 4 can not be true. But I am not sure about the other options.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: I think you can get some idea by just plugging in some values,

$4$. It is not unbounded because,... (try plugging values)

$\frac{1}{3}$. It is not open because

Comment: Nice descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is continuous and $E$ is compact so $f(E)$ is compact which implies that it is bounded and closed. That rules out 1, 3 and 4.

$f$ is continuous and $E$ is connected so $f(E)$ is connected. So 2 is true.