# The range of function $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{1+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives

Given that

> $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:|x| \leq1,|y|\leq1\}.$ function $f(x,y)=\displaystyle \frac{x+y}{1+x^2+y^2}$

where $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ Then the range of $f$ is

> $1)$ connected open set
>
> $2)$ connected closed set
>
> $3)$bounded and open set
>
> $4)$closed and unbounded set

**Solution i tried**- The given function is continous ,so a continous function maps a connected set to connected set and also $E$ is a compact set so its image under the continous function will be compact ,from all this option $2$ will be true ,but my answer is wrong ,

Please help

Comment: Option 2 should be correct. Is it possible that you are reading/posting the question wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you can also try to show/justify why the other options you don't consider correct.

Comment: @kennentropy   if we go with 3rd then bounded is confirmed but what for open ?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is indeed bounded. But can't say the range is an open set.  Maybe a typo in the question ?

Comment: @kennentropy https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460365/let-e-x-y-in-bbb-r2-x-le-1-y-le-1?rq=1  yes my answer is right ,i think answer key is wrong